# Why does isospin symmetry survive chiral symmetry breaking?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, symmetry-breaking, quarks, isospin-symmetry

In QCD there is a breaking of chiral symmetry such that, for the lightest quarks only, we have
$$\langle \overline{u} u \rangle = \langle \overline{d} d \rangle  = \mathrm{const.}$$
where the constant is zero in the symmetric phase and about (250 MeV)$^3$ in the broken phase.

I've never understood why it wouldn't be something more general, like e.g.
$$\langle \overline{u} u \rangle = V_1 \\ \langle \overline{d} d \rangle  = V_2 $$
which wouldn't correspond to a surviving isospin symmetry.

Is there some way of understanding from the QCD Lagrangian or path integral why $V_1=V_2$?

Comment: Our current understanding of spontaneous symmetry breaking in QCD is not very good. You can't directly prove from the lagrangian or path integral why V1 = V2 as far as I am aware. If they were not equal, then the SU(2)xSU(2) symmetry would be badly broken, but we can observe that the isospin symmetry in nuclear physics is a good symmetry, which is exact if you ignore quark masses. So we can confirm $$\langle \overline{u} u \rangle = \langle \overline{d} d \rangle  = \mathrm{V}$$ by checking that it implies a spectrum of hadrons consistent with nature.

Comment: @AbhinayaSinha It seems this is the answer I was looking for. I guess it must be in the path integral somehow but in some hidden way.

Comment: You understand that Chiral/Axial symmetry $U(1)_A$ and isospin symmetry $SU(2)_{isospin}$ are two orthogonal symmetries, right? So, why do you assume symmetry breaking of one should imply the  symmetry breaking of the other?

Comment: @MadMax The condensates in the OP also break the three non-abelian chiral charges, ex partners of *I* . He might be imagining QCD treats them similarly, a proven (V-W)  impossibility...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chiral condensation underlying spontaneous chiral symmetry breaking is not  manifest in the lagrangian or the functional integral (albeit deeply implicit in the latter): it is a nonperturbative property of the QCD vacuum.

Isospin breaking, by contrast,  is largely due to the *small* quark mass differences in the lagrangian, possibly modified by the QCD vacuum—but it's basically a good (unbroken) symmetry of the vacuum, a just-so property only partially understood. These two types of symmetry logically connect in a tractable manner, below.

If you define the scalar bilinears underlying the chiral condensate,
$$S=\bar q (x) q(x) ,\\
  S^a =\bar q (x) \frac{\tau^a}{2}q(x),
$$
you readily see that Isospin leaves $S$ invariant,  but rotates $S^a$,
$$[I^a,S^b(x)]= i\epsilon ^{abc} S^c(x)~~~~~~~\implies \\
S^a(x) = -\frac{i}{2}\epsilon^{abc} [I^b,S^c(x)].$$

The vacuum is isospin and translationally invariant (isospin doesn't break dynamically/spontaneously in QCD), so $I^a|0\rangle= 0$, whence
$$\langle 0|S^a(x)|0\rangle = \langle 0|S^a(0)|0\rangle =0.$$
Focussing on *a*=3 directly implies
$$
\langle \bar u u\rangle - \langle \bar d d \rangle =0.
$$

- The takeaway is that isospin survives in the face of chiral condensation, as the two condensates *must equal each other, whatever* their value.

In sharp contrast to the   arguments that chiral symmetry *must* break spontaneously, there isn't, [can't be](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(84)90230-X), an analog argument for isospin.

In real life, *I* is explicitly broken by the small quark mass difference, about 2 orders of magnitude smaller than the scale of the chiral condensate, so isospin is a good symmetry, and chiral symmetry dynamical breaking is largely unaffected by it.

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting calculation but I think it answers a different question. What I was interested in was why isospin survives at all after the symmetry breaking.

Comment: ? It's a proof that isospin survives  in the face of chiral condensation, as the two condensates ***must*** equal each other, *whatever* their value. Why should it break by more than the explicit mass breaking, that is, dynamically? There are no good arguments it *should*, in sharp contrast to chiral symmetries. What *is* your point, really??

Comment: I'm rereading your answer more carefully. I think your comment "but it's basically a good (unbroken) symmetry of the vacuum, a just-so property only partially understood." is the answer I was looking for. In addition your link to the Vafa-Witten paper may be relevant but I can't access that paper currently.